# How do I change the main WooCommerce account user/email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I developed a storefront on a test server, and used my email address as the one to associate with WooCommerce. Now the site is live and I can't figure out how to associate WooCommerce with the new user I created for the client. There doesn't seem to be an option in WordPress itself, can I just search the database and replace instances of my e-mail address with the client's? Except, of course for the general wp_users table.

Answer (score 4):

From the Dashboard:

- Go to Woocommerce -> Settings
- Click on the Email tab
- Next click on the New order link
- Change the email in the Recipient(s) option to the clients email.
- Click Save changes
- Also in the Email Options change the email in the "From" Email Address box to the clients email as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your response is one way to do it, although I found another. I went to Settings -> General and changed "E-mail Address" to the clients. Then, when I did as you had instructed, it said in italics beneath the input that the e-mails would default to the client's e-mail address.

Comment: That would work as well, I was unsure if you were using your own email address there or not.